# Returning data from an activity to another activity and using that data in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am trying to learn Recycler View by doing a test project, but after failing all day to find this bug I believe I can`t do it. Im using a Recycler View on 2 activities.

- The first activity starts with a null array list of data, so no card views are created on the recycler view.
- You click a + floating action button to open a second activity (startActivityForResult)
- On that activity, we start with an array list full of card views with ingredients details (image, brief description, title), and a null array called dataToBeReturned;
- I get all the data from the card view when a image view on it gets clicked, that data is put on dataToBeReturned (image tag, brief descrition string, title string)

The weird thing happens when I click the android virtual back button (dont know how it is called), and nothing happens, no cards show up, like the data hasn`t been updated or had been lost somehow, but no, I logged some details from the ingredients that were supposed to be passed, confirming they were there. But! When i click a floating action button I have in my second activity, ta-da, the card gets created, the details also gets logged from that function I had earlier...

So in both cases the data is passed, but in one of the cases the card gets created, as far as I understand, the recycler view listens on that arraylist for changes, and when it happens layout gets updated and such, but I wonder why it doesnt happen when I click the back button?

EDIT: Also, if after trying adding a ingredient using the virtual button to come back, if I click add ingredient again and the finish the second activity with the fab, than both cards are created! wtf?

Back button:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finishActivity();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Floating button:

```
mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finishActivity();
            }
        });
```

finishActivity:

```
public void finishActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    ArrayList<Data> dataToReturn = (ArrayList<Data>) searchIngredientAdapter.getDataToReturn();

    for(Data data1 : dataToReturn) {
        ingredientsName.add(new String(data1.getName()));
        ingredientsImage.add(new String(String.valueOf(data1.getImage())));
        ingredientsQuantity.add(new String(String.valueOf(data1.getQuantidade())));
        ingredientsUnit.add(new String(String.valueOf(data1.getUnidade())));
    }

    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(INGREDIENTS_NAME, ingredientsName);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(INGREDIENTS_IMAGE, ingredientsImage);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(INGREDIENTS_QUANTITY, ingredientsQuantity);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(INGREDIENTS_UNIT, ingredientsUnit);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
}
```

onCreateViewHolder (firstActivity):

```
@Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_row_2, parent, false);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(), R.array.units_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        Holder vh = new Holder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

Im sorry if I couldn`t express myself correctly, english is not my native language

Comment: While asking question you have to follow Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable strategies http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `onKeyDown()` was called for sure with your `keyCode == KeyEvent .KEYCODE_BACK`?

If not, try `onBackPressed()`, which is called by `Activity` when Back button is pressed, no matter if virtual or not.

Comment: Did both, no results, same thing :(
There must be something im missing concearning recyclerview updating or something.. or maybe something to do with the activity lifecycle?

Comment: Then check if you passed the data to your `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`, and in your adapter check if `onCreateViewHolder()` is being called properly.